# MySql - How to monitor the amount of reads/writes to the DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Is there a way to fetch the amount of reads / writes made to the entire DB (MySql) in a given period, e.g. the amount of read / writes in the last hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table `GLOBAL_STATUS` in `information_schema`.

Use the field `Com_select` for reads and sum the fields `Com_delete`, `Com_insert`, `Com_update`, `Com_replace` for writes.

These values are cumulativ counters, you should subtract values between an interval:

if t1=t0+60seconds, Com_select at t1 - Com_select at t0 = reads in 1 minute

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I think that the performance_schema (p_s) has basic outputs for 5.5 - might be worth looking into - don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: performance_schema adds a little overhead on your db instance, this is why it was not my first thought but you are right you can study this solution to.